# How do I convert a single byte to a []byte

Tags: string, go, slice

How do I convert a single byte to a slice of bytes in Go?

I have tried this in a few different ways however none of them have worked. I keep getting an error stating: `cannot convert charBytes[i] (type byte) to type []byte`.

The only working method I have found for this so far is to get a character from a string, cast it as a string then recast it as a byte array.

```
characters := "some text"    
for i := 0; len(characters); i++ {    
    var b []byte = []byte(string(characters[i]))    
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Comment: from the error, it looks like you already have a slice? Why not just slice that?

Comment: I'm calling a method that requires slices however I have a byte. I need a slice to call the method.

Comment: This will not work with special characters. What are you actually trying to do? What method do you want to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're actually trying to do:

```golang
    characters := "some text"
    for i := 0; i < len(characters); i++ {
        b := characters[i]
        fmt.Println(b)
    }
```

Your code is confusing (and doesn't compile), but you appear to want to iterate over the string, and for the element you are currently on, convert the character to a byte and print it.  If so, you don't need (or want) to convert anything to a `[]byte`.

---

If you don't want to iterate byte by byte but instead character by character, use a `range` loop. It iterates over `rune`s:

```golang
    characters := "søme spécial text"
    for _, r := range characters {
        char := string(r)
        b := []byte(char)
        fmt.Println(char, b)
    }
```

Comment: `characters[i]` is already of type `byte`. No need to convert it or specify the type of `b`.

Comment: Also this solution is completely ignoring all characters outside the ASCII space. Although that might mostly be due to the same problem in the question.

Comment: @TehSphinX  Thanks!  I'm super tired and wasn't paying enough attention when updating the OP's code.  Updated.

Answer (score 5):

[Spec: Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) does not allow to convert a `byte` to `[]byte`. You may however create a slice that contains that single byte:

```
var value byte

data := []byte{value}
```

Also note that in your case to obtain a slice that contains the i<sup>th</sup> byte, simply use a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

```
characters[i:i+1]
```

Also don't forget that indexing a `string` indexes its UTF-8 byte sequence, and not the runes of the `string`, which does make a difference if the `string` contains runes that are encoded to multiple bytes (in UTF-8).

If you do want to iterate over the runes instead of the bytes, you could use a `for .. range`, or you could convert the input `string` to `[]rune` first.